# Minimum required fields for Billing Address in PayPal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment

What is the minimum fields required for billing address to use PayPal payment gateway? I use Website Payments Standard now. But I would like to know in general if billing address is always necessary for making payment through PayPal account and also by direct payment using express checkout.

Comment: your using REST API or Classic API

Comment: I'm using Classic API.

Comment: before going to check[stackoverflow.com/questions/11191823/is-billing-address-required-for-paypal-direct-payment-credit-card]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in most cases a billing address is not required at all.  That's one of the primary benefits of PayPal for buyers.  They don't have to share their billing information with all the sellers they buy from.

The only time a true billing address would be involved is if you're working with Payments Pro and processing credit cards directly.  In that case, the minimum fields required would depend on how your account was setup.  For example, your account may be configured to decline cards where AVS did not match, in which case the address fields would be required.  If you didn't have it set that way, though, you could leave the address out entirely.